# How to use AND/OR in excel for this?

Tags: excel

I am curious as how I can solve this.

I have a column containing product name(columns AQ) and I have created a column to its right showing(column AR) 1 or 0 if it matches.

this is the code :`=IF(RIGHT(AQ3;3)="MAX";1;0)`

What I wanted to know is... how can I use the AND or OR function  to add "BAS"( so it has both "MAX" and "BAS") in the above code?

I tried this but it returned **#VALUE**.

Failed attempt.`IF(RIGHT(AQ3;3)="MAX";1;0);IF(RIGHT(AQ3;3)="BAS";1;0)`

Thanks for the answers: How to I use "AND" in this?

Comment: You cannot use `AND` there, because `RIGHT(AQ3;3)` cannot be equal to `MAX` and `BAS` at the same time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IF syntax will work like this:

`=IF(RIGHT(AQ3;3)="MAX";1;IF(RIGHT(AQ3;3)="BAS";1;0))`

or an alternative OR version:

`=IF(OR(RIGHT(AQ3;3)={"MAX";"BAS"});1;0)`

Comment: For =IF(RIGHT(AQ3;3)="MAX";1;IF(RIGHT(AQ3;3)="BAS";1;0)) << why do we have just "1" after MAX? it is interesting to know, but it worked. Curious.  Also, for the second one ,=IF(OR(RIGHT(AQ3;3)={"MAX";"BAS"});1;0), why do we have "curly" brackets containing MAX;BAS?

Comment: @user3197575 The brackets are to indicate an array, so that you're trying to equate both `MAX` and `BAS` with the other part.  For the first question, that's because you want to get 1 for either `MAX` or `BAS`, which means that if it's `MAX`, put 1 without checking for `BAS` and if it's not `MAX` then try with `BAS`. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You use it as follows:

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(AQ3;3)="MAX";RIGHT(AQ3;3)="BAS");1;0)
```

`OR` works like that: `OR( Expr1 ; Expr2 ; Expr3? ...)`

If any of those expressions evaluate to `TRUE`, then `OR` returns true.